# Reinstalling IIS 6.0 - Do I need to recreate the Virtual Directories?

Tags: iis, virtual-directory

We are planning to uninstall and reinstall IIS 6.0 on Windows 2003 Server. Do I have to recreate the Virtual Directories after I reinstall IIS or will it be available?

I did look up this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325889) but it does not specify anything about the virtual directories. Any pointers/suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/131b609d-ff3a-488f-a8dd-13044fa623a1.mspx